# Promise.all - Running at wrong time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, angular-promise

I can't seem to get the Promise.all to function as I think it should.

As you can see from the log the promises for data such as "Streak" and "Last Activity"are successfully filled towards the end. However I would like Promise.all to fetch the data only when everything is filled, at the moment it calls once at the beginning when everything is undefined.

First time using promises so any advice is greatly appreciated!

```
function buildResponse (UserId, weekNumber, yesterday, today, lastLogin) {
let currentStreak;
let getLastActivity;
let weekExercise;
let dayTotal;
let yesterdayTotal;

getUserData(UserId);
getUserData(UserId).then((data) => {
if (!data.Item || !data.Item.UserId) {
  console.log("Get User Data Not Found");
} else {
  currentStreak = data.Item.streak;
  getLastActivity = data.Item.lastActivity;
  console.log("Streak is: " + currentStreak);
  console.log("Last activity is: " + getLastActivity);
}
});
getUserData(UserId).catch((err) => {
console.log("Get week data error " + err);
});

getWeekData(UserId, weekNumber);
getWeekData(UserId, weekNumber).then((data) => {
if (!data.Item || !data.Item.UserId) {
  console.log("Week Data Not Found");
} else {
  var yesterdayDay = "Monday";
  weekExercise = data.Item.weekTotal;
  dayTotal = data.Item.Monday;
  yesterdayTotal = data.Item[yesterdayDay];
  console.log("Days total is: " + dayTotal)
}
});
getWeekData(UserId, weekNumber).catch((err) => {
console.log("Get week data error " + err);
});

Promise.all([getWeekData(UserId, weekNumber), getUserData(UserId)]).then((data) => {
console.log("Promise all: " + dayTotal + " and " + currentStreak + " and " + getLastActivity);
});
}
```

Get user data:

```
function getUserData(UserId) {
  const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  const params = {
    TableName: "XXXXXXXX",
    Key: {
      "UserId": UserId,
    }
  };

  return docClient.get(params).promise();
}
```

Log is:

```
    2018-04-09T15:18:35.348Z    43df7459-3c09-11e8-b44c-1726d06a9efd Promise all: undefined and undefined and undefined
 2018-04-09T15:18:35.366Z   43df7459-3c09-11e8-b44c-1726d06a9efd    Update last 
    login succeeded: {
    "Attributes": {
    "lastLogin": "2018-04-09"
    }
    }
    2018-04-09T15:18:35.387Z    43df7459-3c09-11e8-b44c-1726d06a9efd    Streak is: 0
    2018-04-09T15:18:35.405Z    43df7459-3c09-11e8-b44c-1726d06a9efd    Last activity is: run
    2018-04-09T15:18:35.406Z    43df7459-3c09-11e8-b44c-1726d06a9efd    Reset Streak succeeded: {
  "Attributes": {
    "streak": 0
  }
}
    2018-04-09T15:18:35.426Z    43df7459-3c09-11e8-b44c-1726d06a9efd    Days total is: 768
```

EDIT [09/04/2018]

Running it again and this time two of the promises are filled but one isn't. Any advice on what to add to ensure Promise.all waits until everything is filled?

```
2018-04-09T15:41:19.427Z    710113a9-3c0c-11e8-a906-cb494b7c4b47    Streak is: 0
2018-04-09T15:41:19.445Z    710113a9-3c0c-11e8-a906-cb494b7c4b47    Last activity is: run
2018-04-09T15:41:19.448Z    710113a9-3c0c-11e8-a906-cb494b7c4b47    Promise all: undefined and 0 and run
2018-04-09T15:41:19.486Z    710113a9-3c0c-11e8-a906-cb494b7c4b47    Update last login succeeded: {
  "Attributes": {
    "lastLogin": "2018-04-09"
  }
}
2018-04-09T15:41:19.486Z    710113a9-3c0c-11e8-a906-cb494b7c4b47    Days total is: 128
2018-04-09T15:41:19.506Z    710113a9-3c0c-11e8-a906-cb494b7c4b47    Reset Streak succeeded: {
  "Attributes": {
    "streak": 0
  }
}
END RequestId: 710113a9-3c0c-11e8-a906-cb494b7c4b47
REPORT RequestId: 710113a9-3c0c-11e8-a906-cb494b7c4b47  Duration: 2008.58 ms    Billed Duration: 2100 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 38 MB
```

Comment: That would indicate that the values you passed to it weren't promises.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for your comment, what shall i look for to ensure the value is actually a promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont work against the benefits of Promises! In multiple places you do something like this:

```
 getUserData(UserId).then((data) => {
    // This line is executed *somewhen* when the data is found
    // The below line is the real problem:
    currentStreak = data.Item.streak;
 });
```

And thats wrong! You should not pass the data outside the promises `then` handler. Instead put the code that depends on it *into* the `then` handler, so that it is able to access it there, and all your async code problems are gone:

```
  Promise.all(getUserData(UserId),  getWeekData(UserId, weekNumber)).then(([userData, weekData]) => {
    const currentStreak = userData.Item.streak;
    const getLastActivity = userData.Item.lastActivity;

    const yesterdayDay = "Monday";
    const weekExercise = weekData.Item.weekTotal;
    const dayTotal = weekData.Item.Monday;
    const yesterdayTotal = weekData.Item[yesterdayDay];

    /*...*/

 }).catch(/* a proper error handler */);
```